# Bug when create a ViewController by code!

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create new "Window-Based" project in xCode and a subclass of UIViewController name Main View, colour MainView with blue. In My App Delegate i have method:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch
        mainViewController = [[MainView alloc] init]; // mainView is a subclass of UIViewController and be declared in AppDelegate interface.
 [window addSubview:mainViewController.view];
 //[window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

My MainView loaded into Window but it have clearance (image bellow). Anybody can help me to fix it :(
[image]

Comment: There is no need to tag iPhone questions with [mac] unless you're sure they have something to do with writing Mac apps.

Comment: what is MainView a subclass of? Is it a view or a viewController?

Comment: Where are you setting the frame for the window? This blank space looks like the view is shifted up because you may have hidden the status bar. Am I right?

Comment: mainView is subclass of UIViewController :(

Comment: @ledu: why is your view controller named like a view?

Comment: If you rotate the the device to the side and back, does the problem go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem your problem has something to do with the status bar. If you were to get a measurement of that white space I'd put my money on height being 20 pixels.

Is it possible you have a view that is over or under compensating for a status bar that it think may/may not be visible?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have sloved my problem :)